# SSRS 2016 Connect to SQL Server with Force Encryption Enabled

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have 2 Windows 2012 R2 servers in different VLANs.  One is an IIS app with SSRS 2016 installed and the other is running SQL Server 2016.  I can successfully open the SSRS site on the app server side and authenticate in IE.  When the IIS app (third party using ASP.net) tries to use the SSRS I see the below error in the event logs:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

My SQL Server instance is configured with a valid SSL Cert that's signed by our internal CA.  The app server does trust both the root and intermediate CAs in the chain so I don't believe that's the issue.

I've tried changing the `rsreportserver.config` file value for `SecureConnectionLevel` from `0-3`, but none make any difference.

Connectivity from the app to DB on TCP port 1433 is successful.  I Don't think any other ports would come into play here.

Any suggestions on how an SSRS instance can successfully connect to a SQL Server that's forcing encryption?

When I ran the SSRS config manager utility I successfully created the DB and can open the web portal URL in IE on the app server successfully too.

**UPDATE:** I did try setting SQL Server "Force Encryption" to no and restarting SQL Server, but it made no change in the behavior.

Comment: From the SSRS server, did you import the certificate (if needed), go to the SQL Server Native Client Configuration properties in the SQL Server Configuration Manager, and set the Flag to Yes for Force Encryption?

Comment: I think you need continue troubleshooting at the SocketException level. You have verified SQL Server is listening on 1433 and you have verified the app's OS has a network path to SQL Server. What I don't see is an exception that references a SQLClient or SQL Server connectivity failure :). I suggest checking the third party for its connectivity requirements, and if not helpful sniff network traffic from the app's OS.